# Changing the contents of a java file through gradle for different build types in Android

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am working on an Android Project where I have to replace the contents of a java class for only one build type (i.e. release build type) through gradle. I don't want to delete or replace the original contents for different build types.

As an example I have two different build types:

- Debug

  - Original Test.java
- Release

  - Change the contents of Test.java

What I have tried so far is deleting the contents of Test.java and rewriting some different content through groovy (gradle). But once the builds are completed, Test.java is already being overridden with the new content and cannot be reverted back to its original condition. Is there any other way of achieving a mechanism where I can keep different content for different build types in a same file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the usecase for this? In most cases this can be achieved through some logic inside of Test.java ?

Comment: Automated build process where project configuration changes according to the build types.

Comment: Is this a difference in the test suite or in the app itself?

Comment: Also, can you give a concrete use case illustrating why this would be useful?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to provide different versions of the same class for each build type is to create `src/debug` and `src/release` directories in your app module. The directory structure under each of these is identical to that in `src/main`. In particular, you should create a `java` subdirectory with a directory structure that matches your package hierarchy. Now you can create two versions of the same class. Android Studio and Gradle will automatically choose the version of the class based on which configuration you are currently building.

Comment: That means Ill have to change the imports accordingly in all the classes where this specific class is used? In that case Ill end up with a lot of import reorganizing.

Comment: @Ahmed Not at all. You can have the exact same class in the exact same package under both `src/debug` and `src/release`. Gradle will choose which one to use. None of your imports need to change.

Comment: Ok Sure. Will try that in the morning and update on this. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: What would be the case if I am using Eclipse?

Comment: @Ahmed That definitely complicates things. Are you also using the old Eclipse directory structure?

Comment: @Ahmed To use my suggestion, you will have to convert to the new directory structure. The easiest way to do this is to import your project into Android Studio.

Comment: I have a team working on this project and it might be a little harder to move everyone on to Android Studio at this point. Still, Thank You Ill try that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62191/discussion-between-ahmed-and-code-apprentice).

Comment: Can you elaborate this with an example please?

Answer (score 0):

Could you use an if-statement to achieve the same result, e.g. assuming your debug `Test` class looks like this

```
public class Test {

  public void doSomething() {
    System.out.println("debug");
  }
}
```

and your release version is as follows:

```
public class Test {

  public void doSomething() {
    System.out.println("release");
  }
}
```

You could achieve the same result without modifying the file with

```
import grails.util.Environment;

public class Test {

  public void doSomething() {

    if (Environment.getCurrent() == Environment.DEVELOPMENT) {
      System.out.println("debug");
    } else {
      System.out.println("release");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Donal. But I may have left out some important details to explain the question better. I need to modify java code through groovy to change configurations of a project based on different build types.

Comment: @Ahmed Why do you need to modify the Java code? What is the original problem that you are trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: This is exactly the original problem that I am trying to solve. I may have some work arounds for it such as adding the configuration into a buildConfigField, however since the application consists of alot of legacy code, it would be harder to go and change the implementation. Instead a better route would be to just change the contents of a file or two.

Comment: "however since the application consists of alot of legacy code, it would be harder to go and change the implementation" Okay, this is getting a little bit closer to the "why".

Comment: @Ahmed Or you could have said "I need different versions of the same class for each build type." You are trying to solve this problem with gradle and groovy when there are other possible solutions.

Comment: Well once you get in the zone, you just see that particular problem and not how to think of that problem in a different way. I guess thats why all developers should get out of that zone every once in a while.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62201/discussion-between-ahmed-and-code-apprentice).